# SSRS Retrieve BLOB from Oracle Server to text in SSRS Report

Tags: c#, vb.net, reporting-services

I am trying to convert a BLOB from Oracle server to text in SSRS.

I have tried:

```
Convert.ToBase64String(Fields!BLOB.Value)
```

And I have also tried:

```
System.Convert.ToBase64String(Fields!BLOB.Value)
```

But it converts it to UTF-8 encoding and I get these variables `VHaw5nl=`.

I've also tried writing the following code:

```
Public Function Decoding(ByVal s As String) As String  
 Dim rntString As String
rntString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(s)
End Function
```

And then putting this in my expression:

```
Code.Decoding(Fields!BLOB.Value)
```

But I am receiving an error after that.

**How can I solve this problem?**

Answer (score 0):

try:
var myBytes = (byte[])dr["columnname"];
dr is the data reader. Once you get it into an array, you can use Encode to convert it to a string format.